# How can we write testcases to handle malformed data/parsing errors while reading json string using scalatest

Tags: scala, scalatest

```scala
def fetchJson(key: String, value:String) : Future[Option[String]] {}

def processJson(): String = {
    fetchJson(key, value) map {
        case Some(results) => results
        case None => ""
    }
}
```

How can I write test case to cover the scenario where json giving parse errors?

Comment: where do parameters `key` and `value` come from? try to pass incorrect data to them and check `None` case

Comment: Scalatest offers utilities like `whenReady` to test async result

Comment: If you mean testing Future you can use [Asynchronous testing](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/async_testing) in Scalatest.